# Riak 403 error code when try to PUT at http://localhost:8098/admin/cluster from postman

Tags: web-services, rest, security, http-status-code-403, riak

I am trying to make a call to Riak cluster using a web service. I have observed that Riak web console is using http://localhost:8098/admin/cluster to make calls to the Riak.
The problem is that when I try to execute a PUT command from Postman to http://localhost:8098/admin/cluster I have a 403 error message.

Does anybody confronted with this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use the REST APIs used by Riak console. I've already answered your other question about it. HTTP error 403 Forbidden means you are not properly authenticated (and not authorized to call the API), i.e. you are not passing the right HTTP header. I believe Riak console uses a cookie to ensure the APIs are invoked from the console's context. Looking at Riak console requests, I can see that X-Csrf-Token is being passed.